# Supress/filter exception context when raised within a trigger

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

In a Python application I'm catching exceptions thrown from stored procedures on my database as `psycopg2.InternalError`. I've noticed that when they are thrown from within triggers, the exception message comes with whatever message I throw plus the current context.

Since I'm forwarding the error message to the user, I would like to remove the context part from it.

I've done this in the past using regular expressions, but I feel there must be a better way.

Apparently there's a low level function called `PQsetErrorVerbosity` that exists for this specific purpose, but I'm not sure if there's anything available through psycopg2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse messages with regular expressions unless there's absolutely no alternative. It'll break horribly on version updates if the wording/formatting changes, or if the user is in a different locale. Good on you for recognising this problem.

What you should be doing is [using the `Diagnostics` object in the exception](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.Diagnostics).

### Example

Given:

```
create or replace function do_exception() returns void as $$
begin
     raise exception 'eep!';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function call_do_exception() returns void as $$
begin
     PERFORM do_exception();
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('');
curs = conn.cursor();
try:
     curs.execute("SELECT call_do_exception()")
except psycopg2.InternalError, ex:
    saved_ex = ex
```

I get a message with context:

```
>>> print saved_ex
eep!
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT do_exception()"
PL/pgSQL function call_do_exception() line 3 at PERFORM
```

... but it also has a `diag` field:

```
>>> saved_ex.diag
<psycopg2._psycopg.Diagnostics object at 0x7f822e36c150>
```

... with individual message components:

```
>>> saved_ex.diag.message_primary
'eep!'
```